# react intl remove error logs and list keys

Tags: reactjs

I am using https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl

I would like to know if there is a way to remove the errors for

```
[React Intl] Cannot format message: "***", using message id as fallback.
```

Or

```
[React Intl] Missing message: "***" for locale: "**"
```

It makes a lot of noise in the console and make it harder to debug.

Is there a way lo list all the translations keys I am using in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add an `onError` to React Intl and manage it

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this happen is to use a function before components start pulling the localized strings (e.g. App.js).

For example:

```
const filterConsoleErrors = () => {
    const consoleError = console.error;

    if(window && window.console) {
        window.console.error = (...args) => {
            if(typeof args[0] === 'string' && args[0].indexOf('React Intl') > -1) {
                if(args[0].indexOf('Missing') > -1) {
                    return;
                }

                consoleError(args[0]);
                return;
            }

            consoleError(...args);
        };
    }
};

filterConsoleErrors();
```